# Numerical Methods: 4th order Runga Kutta

Tags: numerical-methods

How can I implement the 4th order Runga-Kutta method on $dy/dx$ since it is independent on time? Thanks

Sum:
$$
dy/dx = 0.1y +2,
~~
y(0) = 1.
$$
solve for $y(t)$ from $t=0$ till $t=10$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: There is something wrong in your task. In the equation the independent "time" variable is $x$. You are free to re-label $x$ as $t$, but that is not usually done. Please check again your task and compare with similar exercises that you may already have a solution for.